# Sorting and ranking documents based on key values?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to pull out documents with highest mark for a student in a collection and formed a query below:

```
{ name: "Person1", marks: 20  }
{ name: "Person2", marks: 20  }
{ name: "Person1", marks: 30  }
{ name: "Person1", marks: 25  }
{ name: "Person2", marks: 50  }
{ name: "Person1", marks: 90  }
{ name: "Person3", marks: 990 }
```

An my query:

```
db.mytest1.aggregate( [          
  { $sort : { "name" : 1,"marks" : -1} },
  {$group:
    {
      _id: "$name",
      name: { $first: "$name" },
      marks: { $first: "$marks" }
   }}
])
```

Is there a better way to do this?

And if my scenario was to number the documents based on marks, how can I achieve it?

I'd like to get the following result:

```
{ name: "Person1", marks: 90,  rank: 1 }
{ name: "Person1", marks: 30,  rank: 2 }
{ name: "Person1", marks: 25,  rank: 3 }
{ name: "Person1", marks: 20,  rank: 4 }
{ name: "Person2", marks: 50,  rank: 1 }
{ name: "Person2", marks: 20,  rank: 2 }
{ name: "Person3", marks: 990, rank: 3 }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I really think this is most practical as simple cursor iteration, but more on that later.

The fastest practical way for "small" groupings using the aggregation framework would be using the `includeArrayIndex` from `$unwind` introduced with MongoDB 3.2:

```
db.mytest1.aggregate([
  { "$sort": { "name" : 1,"marks" : -1} },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$name",
    "items": { "$push": "$$ROOT" }
  }},
  { "$unwind": { "path": "$items", "includeArrayIndex": "items.rank" } },
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$items" } },
  { "$sort": { "name" : 1,"marks" : -1} }
])
```

Which produces:

```
{ "name" : "Person1", "marks" : 90, "rank" : NumberLong(0) }
{ "name" : "Person1", "marks" : 30, "rank" : NumberLong(1) }
{ "name" : "Person1", "marks" : 25, "rank" : NumberLong(2) }
{ "name" : "Person1", "marks" : 20, "rank" : NumberLong(3) }
{ "name" : "Person2", "marks" : 50, "rank" : NumberLong(0) }
{ "name" : "Person2", "marks" : 20, "rank" : NumberLong(1) }
{ "name" : "Person3", "marks" : 990, "rank" : NumberLong(0) }
```

Or go a little longer:

```
db.mytest1.aggregate([
  { "$sort": { "name" : 1,"marks" : -1} },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$name",
    "items": { "$push": "$$ROOT" }
  }},
  { "$unwind": { "path": "$items", "includeArrayIndex": "items.rank" } },
  { "$project": { 
    "_id": 0, 
    "name": "$items.name", 
    "marks": "$items.marks",
    "rank": { "$add": [ "$items.rank", 1 ] } 
  }},
  { "$sort": { "name" : 1,"marks" : -1} }
])
```

In the way you want.

```
{ "name" : "Person1", "marks" : 90, "rank" : 1 }
{ "name" : "Person1", "marks" : 30, "rank" : 2 }
{ "name" : "Person1", "marks" : 25, "rank" : 3 }
{ "name" : "Person1", "marks" : 20, "rank" : 4 }
{ "name" : "Person2", "marks" : 50, "rank" : 1 }
{ "name" : "Person2", "marks" : 20, "rank" : 2 }
{ "name" : "Person3", "marks" : 990, "rank" : 1 }
```

Be careful though because we are putting everything into an array for the "grouping" in order to get the "index" position on extraction. This is fine for small lists, but you would never try it with thousands of items.

For 1000's of items then iterate a cursor and rank at breaks instead:

```
var current = null,
    rank = 0;

db.mytest1.find().sort({ "name": 1, "marks": -1 }).forEach(doc => {
  if ( doc.name != current || current == null ) {
    rank = 0;
    current = doc.name;
  }
  rank++;
  doc.rank = rank;
  delete doc._id;
  printjson(doc);
})
```

Which is the same result:

```
{ "name" : "Person1", "marks" : 90, "rank" : 1 }
{ "name" : "Person1", "marks" : 30, "rank" : 2 }
{ "name" : "Person1", "marks" : 25, "rank" : 3 }
{ "name" : "Person1", "marks" : 20, "rank" : 4 }
{ "name" : "Person2", "marks" : 50, "rank" : 1 }
{ "name" : "Person2", "marks" : 20, "rank" : 2 }
{ "name" : "Person3", "marks" : 990, "rank" : 1 }
```

So really, you may as well just do that since it's pretty simple and fast.

Answer (score 3):

Starting in `Mongo 5`, it's a perfect use case for the new [`$setWindowFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setWindowFields/)  aggregation operator:

```
// { name: "Person1", marks: 20 }
// { name: "Person2", marks: 20 }
// { name: "Person1", marks: 30 }
// { name: "Person1", marks: 25 }
// { name: "Person2", marks: 50 }
// { name: "Person1", marks: 90 }
// { name: "Person3", marks: 990 }
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $setWindowFields: {
    partitionBy: "$name",
    sortBy: { marks: -1 },
    output: { rank: { $denseRank: {} } }
  }}
])
// { name: "Person1", marks: 90,  rank: 1 }
// { name: "Person1", marks: 30,  rank: 2 }
// { name: "Person1", marks: 25,  rank: 3 }
// { name: "Person1", marks: 20,  rank: 4 }
// { name: "Person2", marks: 50,  rank: 1 }
// { name: "Person2", marks: 20,  rank: 2 }
// { name: "Person3", marks: 990, rank: 1 }
```

For each name (`partitionBy: "$name"`), this:

- sorts documents by decreasing order of marks: `sortBy: { marks: -1 }`
- and adds the `rank` field in each document (`output: { rank: { $denseRank: {} } }`)

  - which is the rank of the document in its partition: `rank: { $denseRank: {} }`.

    - depending on what you want the rank to be when there are duplicate marks, you can choose between [`$denseRank`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/denseRank/#mongodb-group-grp.-denseRank) and [`$rank`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/rank/#mongodb-group-grp.-rank).
  - on a specified span of documents (the `window`)

    - which is in our case all documents within the partition (their is a `window` parameter that we ignored as its default value is what we need here).