# Storing rank for each collection in a MongoDB set

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to assign a rank to each collection depending on their popularity score which ranges from 0.01 to 1000.

Sample set:

```json
    [{"id":0,"popularity":0.5,"name":"ABC"},
    {"id":1,"popularity":0.1,"name":"DEF"},
    {"id":2,"popularity":500,"name":"GHI"},
    {"id":3,"popularity":50,"name":"JKL"}]
```

My desired result is to end up having the following stored:

```json
    [{"id":0,"popularity":0.5,"name":"ABC","rank":2},
    {"id":1,"popularity":0.1,"name":"DEF","rank":1},
    {"id":2,"popularity":500,"name":"GHI","rank":4},
    {"id":3,"popularity":50,"name":"JKL","rank":3}]
```

So far I have succeeded using the aggregate pipeline, getting the entire set of collections:

```js
    db.restaurants.aggregate([{$sort : {popularity : 1}}]);
```

Then storing the resulted set of ids in an array of ids[] and updating my collections one by one with updateOne in a loop

```js
    for(var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        db.restaurants.updateOne({"id" : ids[i]},{$set: {"rank" : $i }});
    }
```

I was wondering if there is a faster, more efficient way to do this entirely in the database side, considering that I have millions of collections stored, since my current method is very time consuming.

I should also mention that my version of mongodb is v4.4.10.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

With MongoDB v5.0+, you can use `$setWindowFields`. Use `$merge` to update back to the collection.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $setWindowFields: {
      partitionBy: null,
      sortBy: {
        popularity: 1
      },
      output: {
        rank: {
          $rank: {}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "collection",
      "on": "id",
      "whenMatched": "replace"
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Vl7P_pv3FYA) for your reference.

Comment: Unfortunately my version is v4.4.10 and my provider can not update it further.

Comment: @Meteor I think you could reference the idea in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44587829/sorting-and-ranking-documents-based-on-key-values/44588463#44588463), but I doubt it will help since your collection is huge and without any specific grouping key. If this case still doesn't help, you may want to check out [bulk operation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/Bulk/) to speed up your update operations.

Comment: I am already using bulk operation (didn't want to include in my example cause it would be confusing) and it's still too slow...